Keyboard-shortcut in VS for jumping back to code from Inspection Result
I am describing a specific use, but I suspect the solution will help me in other listings in VS. It's just easier to describe the problem with a specific scenario:
I am in Visual Studio 2022 with Resharper in a c# file, and I do alt-ctrl-shift-A to get the context menu, that allows me to select "Inspect Code" context menu item.
Then a window appears named "Inspection Result".
Now, if there are no code issues, the focus ends up in "Inspection Result" so when I click ctrl-f4 (close window) it closes the Inspection Result. But I want to close the c# file.
How do I get from Inspection Result and back into the code, so I can close it or continue to work on it (using keyboard only, obviously :-)?
